# Preserve consecutive whitespace with shlex

Tags: python

I'm using shlex to parse a csv file, and need to retain consecutive whitespace characters like so...

```
line = 'a, b, "c, z",,,d,e,f'
spltr = shlex.shlex(line)
spltr.whitespace += ','
parts = list(spltr)
print parts
```

It returns `['a', 'b', '"c, z"', 'd', 'e', 'f']` when I really want `['a', 'b', '"c, z"', '', '', 'd', 'e', 'f']`. How can I tell shlex to preserve these consecutive whitespace characters instead of dropping them?

Comment: "*I'm using shlex to parse a csv file*": why? What's wrong with the `csv` module?

Comment: The file is 10GB, and I'm using multiprocessing to speed things up.

Comment: So why are you using `shlex` in the first place?

Comment: The multiprocessing example I found used it. The examples of CSV I've seen are all used on files not chunks of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work with `shlex`, on a command line the number of whitespace characters is not relevant.

```
spltr.whitespace += ','
```

There is no difference between one or more whitepaces, they get processed as a single item.

Here is a working solution:

- please split your input file into chunks of lines
- send your chunks to another process if you like
- use `StringIO` so you can have file semantics on each chunk
- use `csv` module

working example:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import StringIO
>>>
>>> line = 'a, b, "c, z",,,d,e,f'
>>> file_like = StringIO.StringIO(line)
>>>
>>> csvreader = csv.reader(file_like, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', skipinitialspace=True)
>>> list(csvreader)
[['a', 'b', 'c, z', '', '', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `csv` module:

```
import csv
from cStringIO import StringIO

line = 'a, b, "c, z",,,d,e,f'
parts = next(csv.reader(StringIO(line), skipinitialspace=True))
```

Note that this removes the quotes in the output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c, z', '', '', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Which is slightly different than what you said you wanted, but hopefully no big deal (maybe it's even better this way?).

Now, you also said you're concerned about performance and multi-core parsing.  So I suggest you do streaming reads instead of using StringIO to buffer as I did for my example above.  You can open the file in each process, `file.seek()` to the appropriate location, and read from there, stopping when the file location gets to the end for the particular process.

Or, if you want high performance in a single process, look at NumPy, which can read CSV files efficiently if they are rectangular (each row has the same number of columns with the same data types).

Comment: do you think `pypy` could provide performance gain comparable or better than `NumPy` for that?

Comment: @dnozay: I have no idea.  NumPy is available virtually everywhere, so I'd tend to use that.

Comment: I bet numPy is faster, it's compiled code, versus this weird virtual machine which is pypy. Besides, numPy works within your existing python, it's a lot easier to install.